# MediatorLiveData This source was already added with the different observer in activity when navigate with onbackpressesed between activities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata, mediatorlivedata

I have an ugly error with mediator live data... and I can´t understand the problem.
I have one activity A which asks for messages to the backend, when I come back from the background I always have to refresh again if there is data, then always call in onResume() to get the info , my code is as follows

```
private var userSource: LiveData<Resource<List<Messages>>> = MutableLiveData()
private val _userMessages = MediatorLiveData<List<Messages>>()
val userMessages: LiveData<List<Messages>> get() = _userMessages

fun getMessages()= viewModelScope.launch(dispatchers.main) {
        _userMessages.removeSource(userSource) // We make sure there is only one source of livedata (allowing us properly refresh)
        withContext(dispatchers.io) {
            val token = session.getSessionUser().accessToken
            userSource =
                getUserMessages(token = token  )
        }
        _userMessages.addSource(userSource) {
            if (it.status == Resource.Status.SUCCESS){
                _userMessages.value = it.data
            }
            _isLoading.value = it.status
            if (it.status == Resource.Status.ERROR) _snackbarError.value =
                Event(R.string.TEXT_ALERT_SERVER_ERROR)
        }
    }
```

When I click on an item in the list, I go to another activity B which has a logic identical to the previous one but obviously with a different backend call. When I go back from activity B to activity A I have onActivityResult and I request the data for activity A again, everything works fine. 
The problem is the following, now I have had to add an activity C, which is navigated from activity B.

```
A --> B --> C
A <-- B <-- C
```

This activity C has the same call logic as the previous activities. The problem is that when I pressed on back from activity  C and go to B,  Activity B, I get an error in Activity A.

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This source was already added with the different observer
        at androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData.addSource(MediatorLiveData.java:89)
        at com.makeclub.home.menu.messages.MessagesViewModel$getMessages$1.invokeSuspend(MessagesViewModel.kt:86)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I add breakpoints in Activity A onResume and onActivityResult but never is called!!

I don´t understand the problem...

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

dont add it on OnResume put them at Oncreate.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a solution to this question, in your fragment "override fun onStop()" method, remove the mediatorLiveData datasource.

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    viewMode.mediatorLiveDateObject.removeDataSource(dataSource)
}
```